# React PropTypes.array has keys with type string

Tags: reactjs

My Component has a Property defined as array but i cant iterate the values by numeric keys. It seems that the keys are of type string.
Am I missing something?

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
    render () {
        let parse = [];
            for (let i in Object.keys(this.props.test)) {
                parse.push(
                    <div key={i}>
                        {i} {typeof i} {this.props.test[i]}
                    </div>
                )
    }
    return (
        <div> 
            {parse}
        </div>
    )
    }
}

Test.propTypes = {
    test: React.PropTypes.array
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Test test={["a", "b", "c"]} />, 
   document.getElementById('main') 
);
```

Shows that the keys of Property Test are strings.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/ugrpla/pen/LypjrG)

Comment: Because keys of an JavaScript object are always strings

Comment: Even if you write `{1: 'foo'}`, the `1` will become a string

Comment: But i defined the Property as ["a", "b", "c"].
And it has PropTypes set to array also.

Comment: See the docs of `Object.keys` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: *Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings*

Comment: what do you means by **i cant iterate the values by numeric keys** ?? if you use `this.props.test[0]` it will work properly, when you use `for` loop may be type of index will be `string`, i tried using `map` there type of index is number. check this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVyrpE?editors=0010 Btw you don't need to use `Object.keys()` to iterate the array, you can directly use `for` or `map` on array.

Comment: My problem was somewhere else. I fetch the properties. The component rendered twice, before and after the data fetch. In the first run iterating the empty array resulted in an error message. And by misunderstanding of Object.keys i misinterpreted my debugging. thx for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if you want to iterate with numerical keys, just use `map`, `forEach` or a classic `for` `i < length` loop, here is the `map` example:

```
this.props.test.map((el, i) => (
  <div key={i}>
    {i} {typeof i} {el}
  </div>
))
```

Using non-numerical keys are totally fine. Moreover, sometimes using indexes as keys is not a good idea.

For example if your array may change sorting or delete/insert elements at the beginning or the middle, React may do many unnecessary operations (unmout/re-mount them)

Answer (score 1):

You can better organise your code calling map function on your array,

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const {test} = this.props;

    return (
       <div>
         {test.map((t, i) =>
            <div key = {i}>{i} {typeof i} {t}</div>
         )}
       </div>
    );
   }
}

Test.propTypes = {
  test: React.PropTypes.array
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Test test={["a", "b", "c"]} />, 
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Comment: `Object.keys` is not required here, its already an array of strings, you can directly use map on `this.props.test` :)